# Convert angle value to a number in specific range

Tags: convergence-divergence, angle

I'm working on an Android component which is a circular component. It represents a specific range of weight.
My math knowledge is very limited. I would like to convert angle in this specifica range.
For example, angles comes from 0 to 360. And my scale is from 45 to 100.
How can I convert angle values considering my scale?

Comment: Including 45 and 100?

Comment: For linear scaling use $45+\frac{\theta}{360}(100-45)$

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh Yes

Comment: @user1131274 THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your value is 0. So on scale must be 45.

For angle 360 on scale 100.

We have already 45 + 55 * $\frac{\text{angle}}{360}$

Comment: Exactly what I looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find constants, $a$ and $b$, so that the function $f(x) = ax + b$ has the properties $f(0) = 45$ and $f(360) = 100$:

\begin{align}
   f(0) &= 45 \\
   a \cdot 0 + b &= 45 \\
   b &= 45 \\
   \hline
   f(360) &= 100 \\
   a \cdot 360 + b &= 100 \\
   360a + b &= 100\\
   \hline
   360a + 45 &= 100 \\
   360a &= 55 \\
   a &= \dfrac{55}{360} \\
   a &= \dfrac{11}{72} \\
   \hline
   f(x) &= \dfrac{11}{72}x + 45
\end{align}